# returning JSON values (objects) via ajax

Tags: ajax, json

Suppose i have a json file like this:

```
{
  "content": {
    "statistics": [
      {
        "key": "aaaa",
        "value": {
          "hits": 0,
          "misses": 0,
          "errors": 0,
          "hitRate": 0.0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "bbbb",
        "value": {
          "hits": 0,
          "misses": 0,
          "errors": 0,
          "hitRate": 0.0
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "cccc",
        "value": {
          "hits": 0,
          "misses": 0,
          "errors": 0,
          "hitRate": 0.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "enabled": false
  },
  "meta": {
    "httpCode": 000
  }
}
```

and using this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var key=data["key"];
        console.log(key);
    }
});
```

but this code above does not work, it doesn't return keys from the json. How do I display out all the values for keys, values, hits..etc? Many thank for your help

Comment: does `console.log(data)` display the JSON object?

Comment: yes is does, this one: Object {content: Object, meta: Object}
content: Object
meta: Object
__proto__: Object

Comment: I think you totally misunderstand the json format. data.content.statistics[0].key would be aaaa. For your code to work it should look like {key:["aaaa","bbbb","cccc"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `key` exists at a different level in the hierarchy than you are checking.

Given `data` is your JSON object, `key` exists at `data.content.statistics[index].key`. Therefore, to print out each key, you'd need the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.content.statistics.length; i++) {
    var key = data.content.statistics[i].key;
    console.log(key);
}
```

You could then access each of the values as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.content.statistics.length; i++) {
    var key = data.content.statistics[i].key;
    var val = data.content.statistics[i].value;

    console.log("Hits: " + val.hits);
    console.log("Misses: " + val.misses);
    console.log("Errors: " + val.errors);
    console.log("Hit Rate: " + val.hitRate);
}
```